# Using multiprocess to build Gurobi expression in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, gurobi

First of all, I am working with jupyter-notebook, python version 3.5, and Gurobi 7.0.2 with its python interface, all on Red Hat.

This is the context of my problem: I want to solve a Quadratic problem, which has a huge number of variables. It takes over 1-2 hours, to build the objective function.

I thought about using NumPy GPU acceleration but the expression is a little bit tricky, and so, this can't be a solution.

Therefore, I am trying to build the objective function using several threads. However, I am getting an error that I don't know how to handle it.

I simplified my code, so it can be more readable (The error is still the same).

```
from gurobipy import *
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
mp.set_start_method('fork')

def function(obj,q):

    print('We enter')
    obj = x*x + x*y + y*y + y*z + z*z + 2*x
    q.put(obj)
    print('We end')

m = Model("qp")
obj = QuadExpr()

x = m.addVar(ub=1.0, name="x")
y = m.addVar(ub=1.0, name="y")
z = m.addVar(ub=1.0, name="z")
q = mp.Queue()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for k in range (4): 
        p = mp.Process(target=function, args=(obj,q,))
        p.start()
        obj+=q.get()
        p.join()
m.setObjective(obj)

# Add constraint: x + 2 y + 3 z <= 4
m.addConstr(x + 2 * y + 3 * z >= 4, "c0")

# Add constraint: x + y >= 1
m.addConstr(x + y >= 1, "c1")

m.optimize()

for v in m.getVars():
    print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

print('Obj: %g' % obj.getValue())
```

Output:

```
We enter
We end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GurobiError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-c71f0667f39b> in <module>()
     17         p = mp.Process(target=function, args=(obj,q,))
     18         p.start()
---> 19         obj+=q.get()
     20         p.join()
     21 m.setObjective(obj)

quadexpr.pxi in gurobipy.QuadExpr.__iadd__ (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:39916)()

quadexpr.pxi in gurobipy.QuadExpr.add (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:35739)()

linexpr.pxi in gurobipy.LinExpr.add (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:29245)()

GurobiError: Unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) for LinExpr addition argument
```

I guess from this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/fwLRrWLLJqo, that it is something related with pickling the gurobi expression that I output from the queue, but I am not really sure.

Do you know how can I solve this? Is there any other way to "return" results from process that could work here?. I would like to avoid writing in the disk, due to it slowness (maybe the last resource :S).

Thank you in advance :).

P.D. The slow part of my code is this one, which I tried to split it in several process:

```
# var is an array of GRB.BINARY
# D=edge_costs
def penalty_function(var,obj,D):
    num_nodes = len(var)
    for i,fil in enumerate(D):
        for j,val in enumerate(fil):
            # -x*D*x
            if val!=0:
                obj+=var[i]*var[j]*val
            # -x(i)x(j)*min(Ds)
            if(j>i):
                for k in range(num_nodes):
                    if(not j==i):
                    minval=min(D[j][k],D[i][k])
                        if (minval!=0 ):
                            obj+=var[i]*var[j]*minval
    return obj
```

Comment: More information would be helpful. How many variables? For the objective function, how many nonzeros in the linear term, and how many nonzeros in the quadratic term? What is the memory and processor on the computer?

Comment: Yes, I am working with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 870  @ 2.93GHz and 16GB of memory. A reduced problem has: Optimize a model with 1 rows, 414 columns and 414 nonzeros
Model has 4257 quadratic objective terms
Variable types: 0 continuous, 414 integer (414 binary)

Comment: Btw, I am not looking for the optimal solution. I guess that the problem is to long to be solve. Until now I have set a timeout and I am okay with the result that gurobi gives me. My problem come from before optimizing, when I am constructing the objective function. However, I will add more information about objective function.

Comment: Note that the multiplication of two binary variables can be linearized easily. No need to use a quadratic term here.

Comment: How can I model it?, Maybe something like this?: x*y equal to z with two constraints z≤x and z≤y (when they are binary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Gurobi Optimizer does not support multiple threads for model building. Even if we did, model building is almost never the bottleneck in properly written applications.

In this case, you have a lot of expressions that look like x + x + x.  While correct, that is very inefficient - it is much better to write 3*x.  Here is a quick rewrite of penalty_function:

```
# var is an array of GRB.BINARY
# D=edge_costs
def penalty_function(var,obj,D):
    num_nodes = len(var)
    for i,fil in enumerate(D):
        for j,val in enumerate(fil):
            # -x*D*x
            if val!=0:
                obj+=var[i]*var[j]*val
            # -x(i)x(j)*min(Ds)
            if(j>i):
                minval = sum(min(D[j][k],D[i][k]) for k in range(num_nodes))
                if minval != 0:
                    obj += var[i]*var[j]*minval
    return obj
```

And a quick workaround for the issue raised by Erwin Kavelagen is to [set PreQLinearize=1](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/preqlinearize.html).

**Edit**: We can make penalty_function slightly more efficient by combining the two var[i]*var[j] terms:

```
def penalty_function(var,obj,D):
    num_nodes = len(var)
    for i,fil in enumerate(D):
        for j,val in enumerate(fil):
            # -x(i)x(j)*min(Ds)
            if(j>i):
                val += sum(min(D[j][k],D[i][k]) for k in range(num_nodes))
            # -x*D*x
            if val!=0:
                obj += var[i]*var[j]*val
    return obj
```

Comment: The set PreQLinearize params works really well. I will set this as solved because of the first part of your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After adding Greg Glockner improvements, I realized that I could use numpy and multithreads in a different way. I add it here in case someone is interested in it.

```
def parallel_function(D,num_nodes,start,end):     
    minD=[]
    if(end>num_nodes-1):
        end=num_nodes
    for i in range(start,end,1):
        # fill with 0 (triangular matrix)
        minval=[0]*(i+1)
        for j,val in enumerate(D[i]):
            if(j>i):
                minval.append(sum(min(D[j][k],D[i][k]) for k in range(num_nodes)))
        minD.append(minval)
    return minD

def penalty_function(var,obj,D,num_nodes):
    num_process=8
    inc=math.ceil(num_nodes/num_process)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_process)              # start 8 worker processes
        minval=pool.starmap(parallel_function, [(D,num_nodes,u*inc,u*inc+inc) for u in range(8)])
        pool.close()
    minD=[]
    for x in minval:
        minD=minD+x
    obj+=np.array(var).dot((np.array(minD)+np.array(D))).dot(var)
    return obj
```